# Dectect if Uploaded file is corrupted

Tags: asp.net, upload

I have made a upload page to upload dll to server, many of the times the dll gets corrupt on upload.
How do I detect that the file uploaded is corrupt or not in asp.net?

Comment: can you specify the size of that dll you are uploading...

Comment: How about this:
get a md5 checksum from client side(activex, or manual compute)

upload file and post the md5 checksum.

Compare the checksum of uploaded file(computed at service side) and the posted checksum.

Comment: The file size is 47mb and the maxRequestLength="51200"

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to detect a corruption without something else as a reference (eg, MD5 sum). Any file can contain any data, so simply inspecting a file without any semantics at all won't tell you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only dll files that get corrupted? Not sure why this would be the case, but zipping them might help? You would need to create some kind of late binding test method or something to test the dll.